# Hyphens in project names in setuptools 0.7?

Tags: python, setuptools, buildout

I have a nice little script library called [buildout-starter](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/buildout-starter) which makes creating Buildout projects really easy.

Then, the latest Buildout declared a dependency on `setuptools>=0.7`, so I had to upgrade my `setuptools` here to be compliant.

After the upgrade, `setuptools` now fails along with my Buildout. Whereas the following would work before 0.7, it now fails:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "tornado-chat-example",
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    packages = find_packages('src'),
    package_dir = { '': 'src'},
    install_requires = [ 'setuptools', ],
)
```

My `src` directory looks like this:

```
src
├── tornadochatexample
└── tornado_chat_example.egg-info
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Develop: '/home/naftuli/tornado-chat-example/.'
Installing python_section.
Couldn't find index page for 'tornadochatexample' (maybe misspelled?)
Getting distribution for 'tornadochatexample'.
Couldn't find index page for 'tornadochatexample' (maybe misspelled?)
While:
  Installing python_section.
  Getting distribution for 'tornadochatexample'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'tornadochatexample'.
```

Like I mentioned before, this example would seemingly run on `setuptools` 0.6, but now fails in the latest `setuptools` 0.7. How can I get this to work? I'd like my project to be named `tornado-chat-example` but have a package of `tornadochatexample`. How can I make this work?

Comment: Not sure here, maybe you should directly contact the `setuptools` guys? This might just as well be a bug.

Comment: Is it possible that 0.7 is enforcing [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)?  "Package and Module Names
Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged."

Comment: I have no idea, but my actual package name as mentioned above is `tornadochatexample`. The PyPI name is `tornado-chat-example`.

Comment: Previously, internally the name would be changed to use underscores. It appears that that implicit transformation is now failing.

Comment: See http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2011-August/017935.html and http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2011-August/017936.html. Still, if this is now no longer working, there is a bug somewhere.